# How we can send an image to the server in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, file-upload, swagger, send

I try yo send the image that i get from local gallery to swagger. The required type for image is string ($binary). How can i send it to server? I've search in google and youtube but it seems i still doesn't find the tutorial i need, sometimes it is in activity than fragment. So i confused. I'm new in kotlin. This is my fragment code: https://codeshare.io/3AMWY6 and this is my viewModel code: https://codeshare.io/Lw0xnl Thank you for answering..

Answer (score 1):

**Recomended Method**

If you are uploading image to server. You can choose type of MultipartBody.Part and sending with retrofit you can find your solution in this tutorial Simplified Coding
[Android Upload File to Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k67-FgvdlYw)

---

**Requested Method**

Firstly you can convert image to bitmap which is consist of bits then convert to string with this [library](https://github.com/pixelcarrot/base64image) written by pixelcarrot or you can convert it manually

```kotlin
private fun btmpToString(){
     val outputStream= ByteArrayOutputStream()
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
     val byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray()
     return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray , Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```